# Should I escape content when sending HTML in JSON from server to client?

Tags: javascript, html, json, escaping, single-page-application

I need to send HTML content from server to client in order to display them (user can post comments in HTML format and those comments can be viewed by others). My client is rich JS app which communicates with server via JSON API.

My question is if I return such response:

```
{
  commentId: '123',
  authorId: '123',
  comment: 'possible HTML here'
}
```

should I escape content in `comment` field on server and send escaped to client or should I send original HTML and have client take care of escaping if required? What is common practice?

Also to display that HTML should I sanitize it somehow (e.g. remove script tags etc)?

Comment: I would just send the HTML string as-is to the server and process it there. If you're not doing front-end templating there's no reason to do it there IMO.

Answer (score 1):

There is no common practice, for example if the user submits some HTML with script tag, you can save all that content in your DB after sanitizing it with for example http://htmlpurifier.org/ library, which allows you to specify which tags to strip which to keep...

Or you can save the submitted HTML as is, and sanitize it in client side using for example https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer (https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/plugin/html-sanitizer.js?r=5170) which does nearly same things as HTMLPurifier, but on client side

Sanitizing HTML is cpu intensive task, so in first case you will use your server's cpu, in second case you will use user's

You choose

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions mixed here.

1. Should I escape JSON string [manually]?
2. Should I escape HTML in it?

For the first question the answer is NO. You have to use whatever facility to create JSON string out of your data structure your language offers for.

For the second question - it depends. If your users **indeed allowed** to post HTML comments and you had verified them - obviously you don't have to escape this HTML.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should escape it. Otherwise it will not be a valid JSON and you will have problems in the front-end. I'll suggest to use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js on the client side and some alternative of it in your backend. JSON.parse and JSON.stringify will guarantee that you pass valid data.

Answer (score -1):

You should escape JSON content.

I would recommend escaping it before sending it in JSON format, as it makes JSON more robust in the process.

The format can break on " and special characters for example (had both cases break my JSON object, resulting in a broken website!).